# Creating Tables in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

Guys I've got a script that queries services in remote computers.  It runs 2 nested foreach loops, 1 for the computer list and the internal one for the services list.  I want to capture the output of the process in a 2-dimensional array.

```
The desired output should be like this:

Computer    Service   State   StartupMode
-------------------------------------------
data         data      data     data
data         data      data     data
data         data      data     data
data         data      data     data
```

I already obtained the data and presented it on the console but have failed to store it in a multicolumn array.
Hash tables can only accept 2 columns.

Comment: You can use a 1D array whose elements are arrays of size 4 to store the data in your inner-loop. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/01/23/array-literals-in-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try This one:

Using WMI because `Get-Service` missing the `StartupMode`

```
$Array = @()
$Computers = "Computer1","Computer2","Computer3"

Foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
$Services = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $Computer | Select name,state,startmode
    Foreach ($Service in $Services)
    {
    $Row = "" | Select Computer,Service,State,StartupMode
    $Row.Computer = $Computer
    $Row.Service = $Service.Name
    $Row.State = $Service.State
    $Row.StartupMode = $Service.StartMode
    $Array += $Row
    }
}

$Array
```

Answer (score 20):

You could create objects with all those properties yourself by doing something like the following:

```
$yourData = @(
    @{Computer="Data";Service="Data";State="Data";StartupMode="Data"},
    @{Computer="Data";Service="Data";State="Data";StartupMode="Data"},
    @{Computer="Data";Service="Data";State="Data";StartupMode="Data"},
    @{Computer="Data";Service="Data";State="Data";StartupMode="Data"}) | % { New-Object object | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $_ -PassThru }

$yourData
```

Answer (score 4):

Slight variation on @Dan's answer, using `[pscustomobject]` per [this MicroSoft blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.2#creating-objects).

```
$yourData = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{Computer="Data";Service="Data";State="Data";StartupMode="Data"},
    [pscustomobject]@{Computer="Data";Service="Data";State="Data";StartupMode="Data"},
    [pscustomobject]@{Computer="Data";Service="Data";State="Data";StartupMode="Data"},
    [pscustomobject]@{Computer="Data";Service="Data";State="Data";StartupMode="Data"}) 

$yourData
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding onto the answers that @Dan and @mherzog have provided in case anyone wanted an example of how to add rows to this table somewhat dynamically.

```
$myTable = @()
foreach($computer in $computerList) {
    $col1 = $computer
    $col2 = $(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet)
    $col3 = $(Get-WUList -ComputerName $computer).Count
    $myTable += [pscustomobject]@{Computer=$col1;Online=$col2;Updates=$updateCount}
}
$myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying @Avshalom's answer, you could add the $Service straight to the $Array:

```
$Array = @()
$Computers = "Computer1","Computer2","Computer3"

Foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
$Services = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $Computer | Select name,state,startmode

    Foreach ($Service in $Services)
    {
        $Array += $Service
    }

}

$Array | Format-Table
```