# Replacing Azure VMs location names with custom short names

Tags: arrays, azure, powershell, virtual-machine, hashtable

With this code i want to fetch locations of the VMs in Azure and then replace the locations with short names as shown in hash table. At the end i want to have them in a csv format.  But getting the error of System.Collections.Hashtable
How can i possibly do it as i am not a programmer and know very little about PowerShell scripting.
function get-locations {

$vmDetails = Get-AzVM

$locations = $vmDetails.location

$locations = @ {

```
"westeurope"         = "weu"

"northeurope"        = "neu"

"germanywestcentral" = "gwc
"
```

}

$locations | Export-Csv "C:\Azure Virtual Machines details_$(Get-Date -f dd.MM.yyyy).csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In it's simplest form could this be what you are looking for:

```
$vmDetails = Get-AzVM
$locations = $vmDetails.location                                                                                                     
$THEHASHMAP = @{ "westeurope"  = "weu"; "northeurope" = "neu"; "germanywestcentral" = "gwc"; "centralus" = "cus"}                   
@( foreach ($vm in $vmDetails) {  @{Location=$THEHASHMAP[$vm.location]; VMNAME=$vm.Name} }) | Export-Csv "test4.csv"                        
cat test4.csv                                                                                                    
"VMNAME","Location"
"VM3bvgnig756w5s","cus"
"Dev-Portal-01","weu"
```

Credits to [this previous answer regarding table creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32388896/creating-tables-in-powershell)

Comment: Great. its working but every calue has only one name and ist computer. But i would like to have the actual vm name. How can i possible do this?

Comment: Updated the answer. It is possible to query the Name field as in the new proposed answer.